# scroll event on Hostlistener

Tags: angular

I have defined template

```
@Component({
    selector: 'name',
    directives: [ ... ],
    templateUrl: 'name.html'
})
```

and class

```
export class ProductGridComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
    onScroll(e) {
        alert(window.pageYOffset)
    }

    products = [];
}
```

But it does not shot anything , however when i replace scroll and onScroll with click and onClick it indeed show the alert.

Why does not it work with scroll , does angular2 has any other implementation for it?

Thanks

Comment: I think it should work. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: The code is quite big so i wont be able to , indeed with click it works but not with scroll , weird

Comment: Perhaps the scroll event is fired by the parent component?

Comment: You don't need to migrate the full example to Plunker, just as much that the problem can be reproduced. If you can't provide enough information to reproduce it, then answering is just guesswork.

Comment: I tried to include this class to all parent components withotu success

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/vhGTUGhaQFdMRzqGemOt?p=preview

Comment: Could you figure out why it didn't work?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yep , i figured out somehow my selector when inejcted to another component gets height 0 thats why i actually wasnt scrolling him... weird tho. Thanks for effort :)

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you want to display the host scroll (and not the windows one) and that you are using angular +2.1

```
  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event']) private onScroll($event:Event):void {
    console.log($event.srcElement.scrollLeft, $event.srcElement.scrollTop);
  };
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create a custom directive like bellow

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scroller]'
})
export class ScrollerDirective {

  @HostListener('scroll') scrolling(){
    console.log('scrolling');
  }

  @HostListener('click') clicking(){
    console.log('clicking...');
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

And then assuming you have a html template like

```
<div class="full-width" scroller>
    <div class="double-width"></div>
</div>
```

use the following css

```
.full-width{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.double-width{
    width:400px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

the console will print "scrolling" on running the app if you move the horizontal scroll bar.

Here the key is that - the scoller directive should be in the parent not in the child div.

Answer (score 9):

```
@HostListener('document:wheel', ['$event.target'])
public onWheel(targetElement) {
    console.log()
}
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: please add some explanation for your answer, which makes it more meaningful.

Answer (score 7):

Set `(scroll)="yourFunction($event)"` within the template at the corresponding element.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it by the following code as well:

```
import { HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
 //we'll do some stuff here when the window is scrolled
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who were still not managed to figure this out with any of above solutions, here's a running code that is tested on Angular 12

```
@HostListener('document:wheel', ['$event.target'])
onScroll(): void {
  console.log("Scrolling");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In angular 10 and above, when listening to window events do the following:

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScroll($event: Event): void {
    if($event) {
      console.log($event));
    }
  }
```