# Angular 4 - Scroll Animation

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-animations

I'm creating a webpage having full page width/height div's.
While scrolling down I've two types of methods.

**Scroll on Click**

```
//HTML
<a (click)="goToDiv('about')"></a>

//JS
    goToDiv(id) {
        let element = document.querySelector("#"+id);
        element.scrollIntoView(element);
      }
```

**Scroll on HostListener**

```
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll($event: any): void {
    this.topOffSet = window.pageYOffset;
    //window.scrollTo(0, this.topOffSet+662);
  }
```

**1. How to add a scrolling animation effects?**

Just like :

```
$('.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).height()
    }, 1200);
});
```

**2. And how to use HostListener to scroll to next div?**

Comment: I think it's solution here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748572/scroll-event-on-hostlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748572/scroll-event-on-hostlistener)

Comment: @ObaidulHaque `HostListener` is working properly. Not sure how to add animation.

Comment: Use CSS animation in the functions you call in the Host Listener. Good guide here: https://css-tricks.com/aos-css-driven-scroll-animation-library/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This one is fun. The solution, as with most things angular 2, is observables.

```
  getTargetElementRef(currentYPos: int): ElementRef {
      // you need to figure out how this works
      // I can't comment much on it without knowing more about the page
      // but you inject the host ElementRef in the component / directive constructor and use normal vanillaJS functions to find other elements
  }
  //capture the scroll event and pass to a function that triggers your own event for clarity and so you can manually trigger
  scrollToSource: Subject<int> = new Subject<int>();
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll($event: any): void {
    var target = getTargetElementRef(window.pageYOffset);
    this.scrollTo(target);
  }

  scrollTo(target: ElementRef): void {
     // this assumes you're passing in an ElementRef, it may or may not be appropriate, you can pass them to functions in templates with template variable syntax such as: <div #targetDiv>Scroll Target</div> <button (click)="scrollTo(targetDiv)">Click To Scroll</button>
     this.scrollToSource.next(target.nativeElement.offsetTop);
  }

  //switch map takes the last value emitted by an observable sequence, in this case, the user's latest scroll position, and transforms it into a new observable stream
  this.scrollToSource.switchMap(targetYPos => {
       return Observable.interval(100) //interval just creates an observable stream corresponding to time, this emits every 1/10th of a second. This can be fixed or make it dynamic depending on the distance to scroll
           .scan((acc, curr) =>  acc + 5, window.pageYOffset) // scan takes all values from an emitted observable stream and accumulates them, here you're taking the current position, adding a scroll step (fixed at 5, though this could also be dynamic), and then so on, its like a for loop with +=, but you emit every value to the next operator which scrolls, the second argument is the start position
           .do(position => window.scrollTo(0, position)) /// here is where you scroll with the results from scan
           .takeWhile(val => val < targetYPos); // stop when you get to the target
  }).subscribe(); //don't forget!
```

With a click this is easy to use. You just bind scrollTo to a click

This only works for scrolling in one direction, However this should get you started. You can make scan smarter so it subtracts if you need to go up, and instead use a function inside takeWhile that figures out the correct termination condition based on if going up or down.

edit: rxjs 5+ compatible version

```
  this.scrollToSource.pipe(switchMap(targetYPos => 
       interval(100).pipe( //interval just creates an observable stream corresponding to time, this emits every 1/10th of a second. This can be fixed or make it dynamic depending on the distance to scroll
           scan((acc, curr) =>  acc + 5, window.pageYOffset), // scan takes all values from an emitted observable stream and accumulates them, here you're taking the current position, adding a scroll step (fixed at 5, though this could also be dynamic), and then so on, its like a for loop with +=, but you emit every value to the next operator which scrolls, the second argument is the start position
           takeWhile(val => val < targetYPos)) // stop when you get to the target
  )).subscribe(position => window.scrollTo(0, position)); // here is where you scroll with the results from scan
```

Comment: Your code worked great for me, thanks. Just thought to add, for angular 4> you need to use the import `'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';` or otherwise you'll face "..switchMap is not a function" issue.

Comment: Any idea how to convert this code to work with rxjs 6 ?

Comment: It’s mostly the same, just in the primary sequence, use the pipe operator as appropriate, import interval directly, and replace do with tap, though looking at this now, I’d probably move the do/Tap operation into the subscribe handler.

Answer (score 23):

You can also use the CSS property 
`scroll-behavior: smooth`

in combination with

```
var yPosition = 1000;
window.scrollTo(0,yPosition)
```

Ref: [developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

Comment: Simplest approach

Comment: I'll try that one (less code, aren't you lazy guys ?)

Comment: Better to link the English MDN page :) https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior

Comment: There is a typo, it's : `scroll-behavior: smooth;`

Comment: `Scroll-behaviour` works great in Firefox and Chrome, but is not supported in IE or Edge.

Answer (score 1):

I spent days trying to figure this out. Being a newbie I tried many things and none of them work. Finally, I have a solution so I will post it here.

There are 2 steps:

1. Animate when things appear.
2. Make things appear when scrolling.

**Part 1:** I found out these two great tutorials for newbies:

1. The most [basic](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/63/Angular-4-Animation-Tutorial) one
2. The [one](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-animation-with-angular-6-675b19bc3496/) that actually animates when stuff appears

**Part 2:** I simply find the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203752/5931672)

---

**Part 1 Step by Step:**

1. Add the line `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` to `/src/app/app.module.ts` and then also:

```
@NgModule({
  // Other arrays removed
  imports: [
    // Other imports
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
})
```

2. In the component.ts you want to animate, add: `import { trigger,state,style,transition,animate } from '@angular/animations';` And then:

```
@Component({
  // Here goes the selector and templates and etc.
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      state('void', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition('void <=> *', animate(1000)),
    ]),
  ]
})
```

4. Finally, in the HTML item you want to animate, add `[@fadeInOut]`.

If everything was done correctly, you should now have an animation (but it happens as soon as the webpage loads and not when you scroll.

**Part 2 Step by Step:**

1. Create a file .ts like for example `appear.ts` and copy-paste this code:

```
import {
    ElementRef, Output, Directive, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, EventEmitter
  } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable, Subscription, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
  import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
  //import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
  //import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';



  @Directive({
    selector: '[appear]'
  })
  export class AppearDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @Output()
    appear: EventEmitter<void>;

    elementPos: number;
    elementHeight: number;

    scrollPos: number;
    windowHeight: number;

    subscriptionScroll: Subscription;
    subscriptionResize: Subscription;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef){
      this.appear = new EventEmitter<void>();
    }

    saveDimensions() {
      this.elementPos = this.getOffsetTop(this.element.nativeElement);
      this.elementHeight = this.element.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
      this.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
    saveScrollPos() {
      this.scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    }
    getOffsetTop(element: any){
      let offsetTop = element.offsetTop || 0;
      if(element.offsetParent){
        offsetTop += this.getOffsetTop(element.offsetParent);
      }
      return offsetTop;
    }
    checkVisibility(){
      if(this.isVisible()){
        // double check dimensions (due to async loaded contents, e.g. images)
        this.saveDimensions();
        if(this.isVisible()){
          this.unsubscribe();
          this.appear.emit();
        }
      }
    }
    isVisible(){
      return this.scrollPos >= this.elementPos || (this.scrollPos + this.windowHeight) >= (this.elementPos + this.elementHeight);
    }

    subscribe(){
      this.subscriptionScroll = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(startWith(null))
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.saveScrollPos();
          this.checkVisibility();
        });
      this.subscriptionResize = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(startWith(null))
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.saveDimensions();
          this.checkVisibility();
        });
    }
    unsubscribe(){
      if(this.subscriptionScroll){
        this.subscriptionScroll.unsubscribe();
      }
      if(this.subscriptionResize){
        this.subscriptionResize.unsubscribe();
      }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.subscribe();
    }
    ngOnDestroy(){
      this.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

1. Import it using `import {AppearDirective} from './timeline/appear';`and add it to the imports as:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Other declarations
    AppearDirective
  ],
  // Imports and stuff
```

3. Somewhere in the class do:

```
hasAppeared : boolean = false;
onAppear(){
    this.hasAppeared = true;
    console.log("I have appeared!");   // This is a good idea for debugging
  }
```

3. Finally, in the HTML add the two following:

```
(appear)="onAppear()" *ngIf="hasAppeared"
```

You can check this is working by checking the console for the message "I have appeared!".

Answer (score 0):

The @bryan60 answer works, but I was not comfortable with it, and I preferred to use `TimerObservable` which seems less confusing for other teammates and also easier to customize for future uses.

I suggest you have a shared service for times you're touching DOM, or working with scroll and other HTML element related issues; Then you can have this method on that service (otherwise having it on a component does not make any problem)

```
  // Choose the target element (see the HTML code bellow):
  @ViewChild('myElement') myElement: ElementRef;

  this.scrollAnimateAvailable:boolean;

animateScrollTo(target: ElementRef) {
    if (this.helperService.isBrowser()) {
      this.scrollAnimateAvailable = true;
      TimerObservable
        .create(0, 20).pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.scrollAnimateAvailable)).subscribe((e) => {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= target.nativeElement.offsetTop) {
          window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset - e);
        } else if (window.pageYOffset <= target.nativeElement.offsetTop) {
          window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + e);
        }

        if (window.pageYOffset + 30 > target.nativeElement.offsetTop && window.pageYOffset - 30 < target.nativeElement.offsetTop) {
          this.scrollAnimateAvailable = false;
        }

      });
    }

  }



 scrollToMyElement(){
   this.animateScrollTo(this.myElement)
  }
```

You need to pass the element to this method, here is how you can do it:

```
<a (click)="scrollToMyElement()"></a>
<!-- Lots of things here... -->
<div #myElement></div>
```