# Javascript not executing after implementing routing to AngularCli Project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I had some animations on my home screen via an external javascript file that I included in my scripts array in my Angular.cli.json file.  After implementing routing to my project to use multiple pages, the animations no longer execute when the page loads.  Do I have to change how my javascript is being referenced now that I implemented routing?  Here is my script array for reference:

```
"scripts": [
    "./assets/build/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js",
    "./assets/build/js/plugins.js",
    "./assets/build/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js",
    "./assets/build/js/main.js"
  ]
```

EDIT:
Here is my javascript

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.wrp-site-header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
         didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

 // Make sure they scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
// This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('.wrp-site-header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('.wrp-site-header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    }
}

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: Can you share what animation code you're trying to run?

Comment: see my edit, thanks

Comment: Hi, I'd really urge you not to influence the 'window' object through the JS / TS files. Angular does this for you, you need to tell Angular how you want the behaviour to be.

Comment: This stackoverflow thread seems promising. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199319/angular-4-scroll-animation

Comment: I would agree, but I am getting my js from my designer for the project, so unfortunately that is the code I am stuck with..