# how to scroll the list to top on button click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

could you please tell me how to scroll the list to top on button click in angular ?
I tried like this

```
 scrollToTop(el){
    el.scrollIntoView();
  }

  <button (click)="scrollToTop(target)">scroll to top</button>
```

It scroll the list to top .but it hide my `addressbar` and then user not able see `header` I think it is not a good solution .anybody have any other good solution

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9qxqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can scroll to the top of the list by setting the `scrollTop` property of the container to zero. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxxrfp) for a demo.

```
<div #container class="container">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of items">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button (click)="container.scrollTop = 0">scroll to top</button>
```

---

Here is a simple method that scrolls smoothly to the top of the list. It is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45391882/1009922) by [bryan60](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4855306/bryan60), and adapted to RxJS 6. You can try it in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evc7eb).

```
<button (click)="scrollToTop(container)">scroll to top</button>
```

```
import { interval as observableInterval } from "rxjs";
import { takeWhile, scan, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
...

scrollToTop(el) {
  const duration = 600;
  const interval = 5;
  const move = el.scrollTop * interval / duration;
  observableInterval(interval).pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => acc - move, el.scrollTop),
    tap(position => el.scrollTop = position),
    takeWhile(val => val > 0)).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: example as we do in `jquery` to give `duration` to complete this task.currently it move quickly to top .can we give duration

Comment: Some code for smooth scrolling with pure Javascript can be found in [this post](https://gist.github.com/andjosh/6764939).

Comment: I added a method for smooth scrolling, based on Observables.

Answer (score 5):

You add the `scroll` to your container, so it works on container not on `ul`

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container" #container>
  <ul #target>
    <li *ngFor="let i of items">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button (click)="scrollToTop(container)">scroll to top</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
scrollToTop(el) {
 el.scrollTop = 0;          
}
```

For **smooth scrolling**, use this :

```
scrollToTop(el) {
    var to = 0;
    var duration = 1000;
    var start = el.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        currentTime = 0,
        increment = 20;

    var easeInOutQuad = function(t, b, c, d) {
        t /= d / 2;
        if (t < 1) 
            return c / 2 * t * t + b;
        t--;
        return -c / 2 * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
    }

    var animateScroll = function() {        
        currentTime += increment;
        var val = easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);

        el.scrollTop = val;
        if(currentTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
        }
    }
    animateScroll();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Typescript**

```
ngOnInit(): void {

const scroller = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
scroller?.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  if(scroller?.scrollTop > 300){
    this.windowScrolled = true;
  } else{
    this.windowScrolled = false;
  }
}); 
}



scrollToTop(): void {
    document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0].scrollTo(0,0);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
<a *ngIf="windowScrolled" class="topButton" (click)="scrollToTop()" title="Go to top">
  <i class="pi pi-angle-double-up"><i class="pi pi-angle-double-up"></i></i>
</a>
```

**SCSS**

```
.topButton{
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1030;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 50px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #002266;
    color: white;
    width: 23px;
    height: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```