# Scroll to top of the page with click in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have angular 8 application.

And I have navigation buttons for next and previous. But so I want to archieve that you will be navigate to top of the page when next is triggerd.

So I have this:

```
 <h4 id="heading"  #goUp class="echeq-title">{{ currentEcheqPage.title }}</h4>
```

and ts file:

```
export class EcheqPageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() currentEcheqPage: EcheqPage;
  @Input() currentEcheqPager: EcheqPager;
  @ViewChild('goUp', {static: false}) contentPage: ElementRef;

  // We use template variables to query the components
  @ViewChildren('echeqElement') elementComponents: QueryList<EcheqElementComponent>;

  EcheqElement = EcheqElement;
  elementsChanged = true;
  container: HTMLElement;

  constructor( private echeqService: EcheqService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // document.getElementById ('heading').scrollIntoView();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void { 
    this.showUp();

  }
}

private showUp(): void {
    this.contentPage.nativeElement.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
  }
```

But I don't get error. But also it is not navigating to top of page. IN this case the h4 heading.

So what I have to change?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44441089/angular4-scrolling-to-anchor

Comment: wich one exactly? I don't see solution

Comment: here is direct link https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684827/7302862, alternatively you can use ngx-page-scroll, i personally can recommend this library.

Comment: This is not helping. It can work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75082608/3099784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document object in typescript/javascript, has a function called "scrollIntoView", which can be used to scroll to a specific element. In your case you could created a functions as seen on the snippet below:

```
showUp() {
    const element = document.querySelector('#goUp');
    element.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Hope that was helpful to you. :-)

Comment: It's not in TypeScript only, obviously. TypeScript only provides type definitions.

Comment: echeq-process.component.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null
    at

Comment: Try to change this: 
 <h4 id="heading"  #goUp class="echeq-title">{{ currentEcheqPage.title }}</h4>

into this:  
<h4 id="heading"  id="goUp" class="echeq-title">{{ currentEcheqPage.title }}</h4>

Comment: Just try to create a button, and add the function "showUp", to test if it works, afterwards you could add it to the angular lifecycle hooks ngAfterViewInit() or ngOnInit()

Comment: I made button:  <button (click)="showUp()"  id="goUp" >Go up</button> but when I press I see console.log message, but it doesnt goes up

Comment: Have you made sure to scroll to the bottom before clicking the button?

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution:

```
  @ViewChild('goUp', { static: true }) contentPage: ElementRef;

 ngOnChanges(): void {
   this.showUp();
  }

  showUp() {
     this.contentPage.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, change the following section:

```
 private showUp(): void {
    window.scroll(0,0);
  }
```

Comment: Okay, can you look at that https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrolling-goto-top?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts  the example is not mine but seems to work