# scrollTop not working after adding ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, scrolltop

**I need to add MovetoTop and MovetoBottom buttons**.

**Also I need automatically MovetoBottom  when the page is loading**.

Code is not working.(Only  `scrollToBottom` function works, `scrollToTop` function does not works) after calling the `scrollToBottom` function `ngAfterViewChecked`.

Please help

Here I am sharing my code.

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { Router  } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-review',
  templateUrl: './review.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./review.component.scss']
})
export class ReviewComponent implements OnInit  {
  @ViewChild('scrollMe', { read: ElementRef }) public scroll: ElementRef;




  ngAfterViewChecked() {        
     this.scrollToBottom();        
  }

  public scrollToBottom() {
    console.log(this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop);
    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollHeight;

  }

  public scrollToTop() {
    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }


}
```

**HTML**

```
<div #scrollMe style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;height:100%;">
 Hai
</div>
```

Comment: `i need add to top, add to bottom buttons also i need automatically move to bottom when the page loading`. This statement is confusing .

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51110923/how-to-scroll-the-list-to-top-on-button-click-in-angular)  if something works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `scrollToTop()` function..

```
public scrollToTop() {
  this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop(0);
}
```