# How to implement Scroll animation in Angular 8 with rxjs 6?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have the current template:

```
<div id="top">
...
</div>
```

In the component I have the following method:

```
onTripSave() {
    let top = document.getElementById('top');
    if (top !== null) {
      top.scrollIntoView();
      top = null;
    }  
  }
```

This method scroll to top after finish save which works correctly.
I need the scrollIntoView to not just scroll to top, I would make animation
for that scroll.
Please note that I'm using rxjs 6 so I need code with pipe I guess.

Comment: Read transition in style in component metadata

Comment: I need example cause I'm new to animation

Comment: use a interval(100).pipe(takeWhile(()=>..!reach the top)).susbcribe(()=>move the top) ?

Comment: I've tried to use your code with condition !(window.screenY == 0) and scroll with window.scrollTo(window.screenX, window.screenY-100) and nothing is moving.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I prefer to use angular animation but for now I'm using jquery solution with
the following:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

I found the following solution but it's not valid rxjs 6 code:
[Angular 4 - Scroll Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199319/angular-4-scroll-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into ngx-page-scroll?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll

this will allow you to only have to add one attribute and a target location to a link element, and reference a different element on the page.

```
<a pageScroll href="#monthlyDeals">Monthly Promos</a>
<!-- Content --->
<div id="monthlyDeals">(Content Goes Here)</div>
```

Their documentation is straightforward to follow and worked for an application I needed it for.