# scroll table row on keydown

Tags: angular, angular8

I have added active class to table row on scroll by keypress. however now I want to add the scroll function when ever it is fired.

```
    if (event.code === 'ArrowDown' && this.selectedIndex < (this.products.length - 1)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.selectedIndex++;
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }
    ....
    scrollToBottom(): void {
      try {
          console.log("I am scrolled");
          this.myScrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollTop = ... + 24;
      } catch(err) { }                 
    }



<table class="table" id="tableSearch" #scrollMe>
```

Console log is ok and no error at all, but table doesnt scroll. What I am missing here?

Comment: what is the actual code for  ... + 24;

Comment: You must to use  @HostListener . like this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748572/scroll-event-on-hostlistener)