# Angular scroll host listener not giving scroll values

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material

In my `app.component.html` I have this setup:

```
<app-header *ngIf="navbarTop"></app-header>

<mat-drawer-container id="drawer-container">

    <mat-drawer mode="over" id="side-drawer" [opened]="isOpen">
        <div>
            <!-- Sidenav content -->
        </div>
    </mat-drawer>

    <!-- Main content of the site -->
    <mat-drawer-content id="scroller" (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)">
        <main class="container">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </main>
    </mat-drawer-content>

</mat-drawer-container>

<app-header *ngIf="!navbarTop"></app-header>
```

It's basically a giant `mat-drawer` for the sidenav so that every page can have access to the side menu, and the `router-outlet` in the main drawer/section of the site.

I've tried putting my `(scroll)` binding on the `mat-drawer`, `main`, and the `router-outlet` itself and having it there on the `mat-drawer-content` seems to be the best option so far. Now, on to the actual issue. My .ts has this in it:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
    scrollHandler(e) {
      console.log("scrolled");
      console.log(window.scrollY);
      console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
    }
```

No matter how I go about this, both of the console logs are returning 0, but the event does fire. How can I get an actual scrollY/offsetY/scrollTop/whatever value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40402026/7471023) I was able to fix this issue using `e.srcElement.scrollTop`. If someone could explain why this works over the other things I've tried, that would be great, but at least there's an answer.